# Pyspark, Group by count unique values in a column for a certain value in other column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

That title, yes horrible, sorry. Here' what I mean:
Here's the starting dataset

```
C1   C2
AA   H
AB   M
AC   M
AA   H
AA   L
AC   L
```

Then it would turn into a new dataset with 4 columns:

```
C1   CH   CM   CL
AA   2    0    1
AB   0    1    0
AC   0    1    1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `pivot` api as following with `groupBy` and `agg` and other functions as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
finaldf = df.groupBy("C1").pivot("C2").agg(F.count("C2").alias("count")).na.fill(0)
```

and you should have `finaldf` as

```
+---+---+---+---+
| C1|  H|  L|  M|
+---+---+---+---+
| AA|  2|  1|  0|
| AB|  0|  0|  1|
| AC|  0|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```